# Azure DevOps not expanding macro variable (but only sometimes)

Tags: azure-devops

Azure Devops pipeline template is not properly expanding macro variable. Adding insult to injury, the same template works without a hitch in other pipeline.

Template:

```yaml
parameters:
  - name: "dotnetMonitorId"
    type: string
  - name: "dumpStorageAccountName"
    type: string
  - name: "services"
    type: object
    default: {}
  - name: "k8_service_connection"
    type: string
    default: ""
  - name: "azureSubscription"
    type: string
    default: ""
  - name: "regionId"
    type: string
    default: ""
  - name: "regionCode"
    type: string
    default: ""
  - name: "team"
    type: string
    default: ""
  - name: "mainDB"
    type: string
    default: ""
  - name: "KeyVaultName"
    type: string
    default: ""
steps:
- ${{ each service in parameters.services }}:
  - task: Kubernetes@1
    inputs:
      connectionType: 'Kubernetes Service Connection'
      kubernetesServiceEndpoint: ${{ parameters.k8_service_connection }}
      command: 'login'
  - task: AzureKeyVault@2
    displayName: "Retrieve clientID from KV"
    inputs:
      RunAsPreJob: true
      azureSubscription: ${{parameters.azureSubscription }}
      KeyVaultName: ${{ parameters.keyVaultName }}
      SecretsFilter: managedidentity-${{ service }}-ci
  - pwsh: |
      echo 'macro: $(managedidentity-${{ service }}-ci)'
      echo 'runtime: $[variables.managedidentity-${{ service }}-ci]'
      echo "macro_env: $TEST_MACRO_GKO"
      echo "runtime_env: $TEST_RUNTIME_GKO"
      '$(managedidentity-${{ service }}-ci)' | format-hex
      $TEST_MACRO_GKO | format-hex
      '$[variables.managedidentity-${{ service }}-ci]' | format-hex
      $TEST_RUNTIME_GKO | format-hex
    env:
      TEST_MACRO_GKO: $(managedidentity-${{ service }}-ci)
      TEST_RUNTIME_GKO: $[variables.managedidentity-${{ service }}-ci]

  - task: HelmDeploy@0
    displayName: "Deploy : ${{ service }}"
    inputs:
      connectionType: Kubernetes Service Connection
      kubernetesServiceEndpoint: ${{ parameters.k8_service_connection }}
      command: upgrade
      chartType: filepath
      chartPath: $(System.ArtifactsDirectory)/$(BuildId)/ec-core/Helm/Charts/ec-services.tgz
      releaseName: ${{ parameters.team }}-${{ service }}
      arguments: >
        --atomic 
        --timeout 15m 
        --create-namespace 
        --set dotnetMonitorId=${{ parameters.dotnetMonitorId }} 
        --set DumpStorageAccountName=${{ parameters.dumpStorageAccountName }} 
        --set regionCode=${{ parameters.regionCode }} 
        --namespace ${{ parameters.team }} 
        --set TeamEnv=${{ parameters.team }} 
        --set MainDB="${{ parameters.mainDB }}" 
        --set serviceaccount.clientid=$(managedidentity-${{ service }}-ci)
```

Pipeline use (does not work):

```yaml
- template: _deploy_services.yaml
  parameters:
    k8_service_connection: ${{ zone.k8_service_connection }}
    azureSubscription: ${{parameters.azureSubscription }}
    KeyVaultName: ${{ zone.keyVaultName }}
    regionId: $(regionId)
    team: $(team)
    maindb: $(MainDB)
    regionCode: ${{ zone.regionCode }}
    dotnetMonitorId: ${{ parameters.dotnetMonitorId }}
    dumpStorageAccountName: ${{ zone.dumpStorageAccountName }}
    services:
      - $(name)
```

Pipeline use (does work):

```yaml
- template: _deploy_services.yaml
  parameters:
    k8_service_connection: ${{ parameters.k8_service_connection }}
    azureSubscription: ${{parameters.azureSubscription }}
    KeyVaultName: ${{ parameters.keyVaultName }}
    regionId: $(regionId)
    team: ${{ parameters.team }}
    maindb: $(MainDB)
    regionCode: ${{ parameters.regionCode }}
    dotnetMonitorId: ${{ parameters.dotnetMonitorId }}
    dumpStorageAccountName: ${{ parameters.dumpStorageAccountName }}
    services:
      - ${{ replace(parameters.serviceName , '-service', '') }}
```

Here are some relevant logs from debug run:

Not working:

```
48: ##[debug]loading SECRET_MANAGEDIDENTITY-SUPER-SLURPER-CI
(...)
146: ##[debug]   serviceaccount.clientid=$(managedidentity-super-slurper-ci)
```

working:

```
53: ##[debug]loading SECRET_MANAGEDIDENTITY-SUPER-SLURPER-CI
(...)
151: ##[debug]   serviceaccount.clientid=***
```

As you can see, in both cases the variable is extracted from KeyVault based on the name and then supplied to HelmDeploy@0 task, but in one run it is then expanded properly, but in the other, it's not.

I have checked that they are running on the same version of agent (selfHosted), I also tested other variable syntax `$[variables.variable_name]`, but to no avail. I did a lot of testing with wrapping this into another template, echoing the values (as you can see in template).

```
Starting: PowerShell
==============================================================================
Task         : PowerShell
Description  : Run a PowerShell script on Linux, macOS, or Windows
Version      : 2.212.0
Author       : Microsoft Corporation
Help         : https://docs.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/powershell
==============================================================================
Generating script.
========================== Starting Command Output ===========================
/usr/bin/pwsh -NoLogo -NoProfile -NonInteractive -Command . '/agent/_work/_temp/7425be8c-d1fd-42b4-aaee-84456945a71c.ps1'
macro: $(managedidentity-super-slurper-ci)
runtime: $[variables.managedidentity-super-slurper-ci]
macro_env: 
runtime_env: 

   Label: String (System.String) <1006AB9A>

          Offset Bytes                                           Ascii
                 00 01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 09 0A 0B 0C 0D 0E 0F
          ------ ----------------------------------------------- -----
0000000000000000 24 28 6D 61 6E 61 67 65 64 69 64 65 6E 74 69 74 $(managediden…
0000000000000010 79 2D 73 75 70 65 72 2D 73 6C 75 72 70 65 72 2D y-super-slurp…
0000000000000020 63 69 29                                        ci)
Format-Hex: /agent/_work/_temp/7425be8c-d1fd-42b4-aaee-84456945a71c.ps1:8
Line |
   8 |  $TEST_MACRO_GKO | format-hex
     |                    ~~~~~~~~~~
     | Cannot bind argument to parameter 'InputObject' because it is null.
##[error]PowerShell exited with code '1'.
Finishing: PowerShell
```

Answer (score 2):

Please review the documentation on variable resolution.

The issue here is the difference between *run-time* and *compile-time* variables.

You are passing in a variable using runtime syntax here:

```
    services:
      - $(name)
```

But then referencing it using *compile-time* syntax in your template:

`--set serviceaccount.clientid=$(managedidentity-${{ service }}-ci)`.

Compile-time variables are resolved *before* runtime variables are available. You can't mix them. You're not including details about where the `name` variable is coming from, but it could be as easy as changing it to `${{ variables.name }}` depending on whether or not that variable is available at template compilation time or not.

Comment: Thanks for your comment Daniel! I don't understand how would that be the case. If you take a look at log snippets I posted, both runs resolved to correct variable name. In both cases keyvault step was able to retrieve correct secret from keyvault, but in the not working one variable is not expanded in the last step even though log shows that this variable is provided to the task.

Comment: Ok, I think I get it. With the not working version it gets expanded to `$(managedidentity-$(name)-ci)`, and then from that only the inner variable is being expanded and the outer one is left as a string, am I correct?

Comment: @GrzegorzKawka-Osik Yes, more or less. Basically, expressions in `${{}}` are expanded *before* expressions in `$()` or `$[]` even exist, so you can't really mix them.

Answer (score 0):

This is a workaround that fixed the issue. New pwsh task was added that creates new variable with value of a secret extracted from keyvault and then this value is provided to HelmDeploy task.

```yaml
parameters:
  - name: "dotnetMonitorId"
    type: string
  - name: "dumpStorageAccountName"
    type: string
  - name: "services"
    type: object
    default: {}
  - name: "k8_service_connection"
    type: string
    default: ""
  - name: "azureSubscription"
    type: string
    default: ""
  - name: "regionId"
    type: string
    default: ""
  - name: "regionCode"
    type: string
    default: ""
  - name: "team"
    type: string
    default: ""
  - name: "mainDB"
    type: string
    default: ""
  - name: "KeyVaultName"
    type: string
    default: ""
steps:
- ${{ each service in parameters.services }}:
  - task: Kubernetes@1
    inputs:
      connectionType: 'Kubernetes Service Connection'
      kubernetesServiceEndpoint: ${{ parameters.k8_service_connection }}
      command: 'login'
  - task: AzureKeyVault@2
    displayName: "Retrieve clientID from KV"
    inputs:
      RunAsPreJob: true
      azureSubscription: ${{parameters.azureSubscription }}
      KeyVaultName: ${{ parameters.keyVaultName }}
      SecretsFilter: managedidentity-${{ service }}-ci

  - pwsh: |
      Write-Host '##vso[task.setvariable variable=MI_SERVICE;]$(managedidentity-${{ service }}-ci)'

  - task: HelmDeploy@0
    displayName: "Deploy : ${{ service }}"
    env:
      MI_SERVICE: MI_SERVICE
    inputs:
      connectionType: Kubernetes Service Connection
      kubernetesServiceEndpoint: ${{ parameters.k8_service_connection }}
      command: upgrade
      chartType: filepath
      chartPath: $(System.ArtifactsDirectory)/$(BuildId)/ec-core/Helm/Charts/ec-services.tgz
      releaseName: ${{ parameters.team }}-${{ service }}
      arguments: >
        --atomic 
        --timeout 15m 
        --create-namespace 
        --set dotnetMonitorId=${{ parameters.dotnetMonitorId }} 
        --set DumpStorageAccountName=${{ parameters.dumpStorageAccountName }} 
        --set regionCode=${{ parameters.regionCode }} 
        --namespace ${{ parameters.team }} 
        --set TeamEnv=${{ parameters.team }} 
        --set MainDB="${{ parameters.mainDB }}" 
        --set serviceaccount.clientid=$(MI_SERVICE)
        --values $(System.ArtifactsDirectory)/$(BuildId)/ec-core/Helm/Environments/$(environment)-global.values.yaml 
        --values $(System.ArtifactsDirectory)/$(BuildId)/ec-core/Helm/Environments/$(environment)-${{ parameters.regionId }}.values.yaml 
        --values $(System.ArtifactsDirectory)/$(BuildId)/ec-core/Helm/ServiceValues/${{ service }}.yaml
```